# PHP: What would this be called?

Tags: php, proxy, dns, web-development-server

I'm looking for a php script or any other programming method that will work as a proxy to hit a website by passing DNS. For example, lets say I'm doing development work on another server on ip 8.8.8.8, but the live site is on ip 8.8.4.4. I'd like this proxy script to hit the 8.8.8.8 so I don't have to edit my hosts file. Perhaps it doesn't write directly to the hosts file as that would be a security risk, but say I run a local dns server and pass the arguments off to it with a ttl and then set the server itself to resolve locally.

Does such thing exist? Or what would this be called?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use a config file, with a different IP for testing than for production?

Comment: There is the proxy flag in htaccess, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: Do you want something deployed on the live web server, that would intercept your IP address and proxy to the other server, or something else?

Comment: I could do a bunch of things server side. But that would be more work for me. If possible I'd like to setup a proxy site that perhaps sends host headers of the site they want and the ip they want to get the correct content?